# Calculating minimum potential energies for Thomson problem

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, physics, algorithm, simulation

I have found a table of values for minimum potential energies up to 470 electrons on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem#Configurations_of_smallest_known_energytions_of_smallest_known_energy). However, the method I used for calculating energies is not efficient enough for configurations that have more than 20 electrons.

Could someone optimize the code or provide some insights for optimization, please? (I only need precision up to 2 decimal places)

```
Clear["Global`*"]
force[pt1_, pt2_] := 
  If[pt1 == pt2, {0, 0, 0}, 
   Normalize[(pt1 - pt2)]/(EuclideanDistance[pt1, pt2]^2)];
inetforce[pt_, npt_] := 
  Sum[force[pt, iposition[[i]]], {i, 1, npt}](*initial netforce*);
netforce[pt_, npt_] := Sum[force[pt, position[[i]]], {i, 1, npt}];
potential[position_, npt_] := 
  Sum[Sum[1/EuclideanDistance[position[[i]], position[[j]]], {j, 
     i + 1, npt}], {i, 1, npt - 1}];
coord[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := {Cos[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], 
   Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], Cos[\[Phi]]};
newposition[p_, npt_] := Normalize[p + netforce[p, npt]];
\[Theta] = RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, 470];
\[Phi] = RandomReal[{0, \[Pi]}, 470];
iposition = 
  Table[coord[\[Theta][[i]], \[Phi][[i]]], {i, 
    470}](*initial position*);
position = Table[0, 470];
Table[
 Table[position[[i]] = 
   Normalize[iposition[[i]] + inetforce[iposition[[i]], n]], {i, n}];
 Do[Table[position[[i]] = newposition[position[[i]], n] , {i, n}] , 
  50 + 5 n];
 Round[potential[position, n], .01]
 , {n, 2, 20}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you use `Do` loop to call the inside table `50+5n` times. It seems like you want the `potential` value to converge. Based on this, the following is the tweak to check the potential value till it converges to `2` decimal places.

Firstly, define a function `posR` to call the table inside `Do` loop

```
posR[n_] := 
  Table[position[[i]] = newposition[position[[i]], n], {i, n}];
```

Then, use a `while` loop to check whether the required precision is obtained or not.

```
Table[Table[
  position[[i]] = 
   Normalize[iposition[[i]] + inetforce[iposition[[i]], n]], {i, n}]; 

 While[Round[potential[posR[n], n], 0.001] =!= 
   Round[potential[posR[n], n], 0.001],
  potential[posn[n], n];];

 Round[potential[position, n], 0.01], {n, 2, 30}]//Timing
 (*{2.23081, {0.5, 1.73, 3.67, 6.47, 9.99, 14.46, 19.68, 25.76, 32.72, 
  40.6, 49.17, 58.85, 69.31, 80.67, 92.91, 106.05, 120.09, 135.1, 
  150.88, 167.65, 185.3, 203.95, 223.35, 243.82, 265.16, 287.31, 
  310.5, 334.64, 359.61}}*)
```

The code you posted takes about `9.45 s` to get the same result.

Although, there is an improvement by `4` times, it does not look optimised for higher values of `n`.

One suggestion would be to `memoize` some functions wherever applicable. Check [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! By using your code, the speed is definitely improved a lot. However, the values are still not accurate enough, I have to change the rounding precision to .00001 in `While` so that the final rounding is good enough. About using memorization, I think it can be used in `force`, but it seems to slow down the calculation.